# Can the lower limit of $\frac{d}{dx} \int^x_a f(t)dt = f(x)$ be $-\infty$?

Tags: calculus

I'm self studying math, based on the fundamental theorem of Calculus, $$\frac{d}{dx} \int^x_a f(t)dt = f(x)$$  can the lower limit be $-\infty$?

Comment: If $\int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(t) \, dt$ is defined for some $x_0$, then write $$ \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) \, dt = \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(t) \, dt}_{\text{constant}} + \int_{x_0}^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ and apply FToC to the second term!

Comment: @SangchulLee what is the constant equal to?

Comment: Nothing can be said unless the function $f$ is specified. But as soon as differentiation is concerned, its value is irrelevant for obtaining FToC-type result for $a=-\infty$.

Comment: if you can break down the integral into infinite smaller pieces, $\sum^{x}_{k=-\infty} f(k)$ then wouldn't it be infinity?

Comment: Putting aside the issue that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k)$ is not necessarily related to the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \, dt$, are you asking whether $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \, dt$ always diverges? If so, then the answer is definitely no, much like an infinite sum need not necessarily diverge. For instance, $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \, dx = 1, \qquad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}, \qquad \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}, \quad \cdots. $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, lower limit can be $-\infty$ but only *provided* the resulting improper integral converges. This only means if you first integrate from $a$ to $x,$ get that answer, and then let $a \to -\infty,$ that limit exists.

I'm assuming $f(t)$ is defined and continuous (or sufficiently nice) on $(-\infty,x).$

Comment: why does the function f(x) needs to be continuous? Is the integral of a non-continuous f(x) non-continuous?

Comment: @user14042 Integration theory does not require integrand to be continuous. But it gets complicated in more general cases, and at least one needs to know if it's Riemann integral or other type.

Comment: @user14042 Consider the case of a function $f(x)$ that is equal to $e^x$ for non integers and equal to $x$ for integers. If you integrate it and take the derivative, you'll get $e^x$, which is a different function from $f$. Continuity is sufficient to ensure this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

f(x) depeds only on x not on a.

If f(t)=-t then $\frac{d}{dx} \int\limits^x_a (-t)dt = -\frac{x^2}{2}$ and the lower boun of this function is $-\infty$.

Comment: what's lim sup?